# MySQL Foreign Keys and Querys

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to understand the ins and outs of querying data when I need info from multiple different tables.

Right now I have the following tables.

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `orderNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `orderDate` date NOT NULL,
  `requiredDate` date NOT NULL,
  `shippedDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `comments` text,
  `customerNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`orderNumber`),
  KEY `customerNumber` (`customerNumber`),
  CONSTRAINT `orders_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`customerNumber`) REFERENCES `customers` (`customerNumber`)
)

CREATE TABLE `orderdetails` (
  `orderNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `productCode` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `quantityOrdered` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `priceEach` double NOT NULL,
  `orderLineNumber` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`orderNumber`,`productCode`),
  KEY `productCode` (`productCode`),
  CONSTRAINT `orderdetails_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`productCode`) REFERENCES `products` (`productCode`),
  CONSTRAINT `orderdetails_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`orderNumber`) REFERENCES `orders` (`orderNumber`)
)

CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `productCode` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `productName` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
  `productLine` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `productScale` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `productVendor` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `productDescription` text NOT NULL,
  `quantityInStock` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `buyPrice` double NOT NULL,
  `MSRP` double NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`productCode`),
  KEY `productLine` (`productLine`),
  CONSTRAINT `products_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`productLine`) REFERENCES `productlines` (`productLine`)
)
CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `customerNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `customerName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `contactLastName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `contactFirstName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `addressLine1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `addressLine2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postalCode` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `salesRepEmployeeNumber` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `creditLimit` double DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customerNumber`),
  KEY `salesRepEmployeeNumber` (`salesRepEmployeeNumber`),
  CONSTRAINT `customers_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`salesRepEmployeeNumber`) REFERENCES `employees` (`employeeNumber`)
)
```

What I am trying to figure out is how I would write a query to find the name of the products which were ordered between two specific dates.

I have been looking over the documentation and examples, but I just can't seem to understand it. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Look in the documentation at the keywords SELECT, INNER JOIN, and BETWEEN.

Comment: I have been, looked at a bunch of examples...but clearly missing something. Sorry, feeling slow at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `JOIN` keyword to connect the tables for your query:

```
/* Get product names ordered between two dates */
select distinct p.productName
from orders o
inner join orderdetails od on od.orderNumber = o.orderNumber
inner join products p on p.productCode = oi.productCode
where o.orderDate >= @startDate AND o.orderDate < @endDate
```